# Assigning a static function to a variable

Tags: php

Is there any way to assign a static function to a variable, or accomplishing this in some other way?

```
class my_class{
     public static function my_method($a){
        return $a;
     }
}

$some_func = my_class::my_method;

$someAnonFunc = function($a) use ($some_func){
    return $some_func($a);
}

$inst = new SomeOtherClass(); //Defined somewhere else, in some other file

$inst->someMethod($a, $someAnonFunc);
```

At this point, I get:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'my_method'

Comment: Why do you want such a thing? You may call static methods inside lambda functions without any problem.

Comment: The $someAnonFunc will itself be passed as a parameter to another class' method, which has no knowledge of the static method.  I could of course include the class file, but it seems to me that my approach is cleaner and more reusable ,if it's possible to do so

Comment: You want to hear about [Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: Ok, I guess JavaScript is closer to a functional language than PHP... Isn't namespacing another way of "including" class definitions?  I'm really looking for a way to have some sort of "pointer" to a function, called from anywhere.

Comment: @BinaryDeuce: JavaScript _is_ a functional language, not close to, it _is_

Comment: As Explosion Pills writes below: "Functions are not first class in PHP".  They are not treated as objects all the way/through and through (which is why my faulty code above miserably fails). I'm not an expert, but isn't it one of the key features of a functional language?  I cannot pass a static function to another function, but a lambda is ok.  Why?

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem  Sorry misread.

Comment: @BinaryDeuce because a lambda is an instance of [Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) - anyway php introduced closures, lambdas and all in PHP 5, and such support is often defined as "lipstick on a pig" ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are not first class in PHP .. strings are.  You would have to use `call_user_func` if you wanted to stick with the `::` syntax as one unit:

```
$some_func = 'my_class::my_method';
$someAnonFunc = function ($a) use ($some_func) {
   return call_user_func($some_func, $a);
}
```

Trying to run `$some_func()` will not work since it will treat the colons as part of the function name.

Comment: This wasn't my question but I learned something here - thanks :)

Comment: +1 for _Functions are not first class in PHP_ Functional languages: JavaScript, Lisp, Scheme, Haskell, ... Not PHP, Perl, Java or any of the C-family. That is a big difference and people _should_ know

Comment: +1 Used your solution. Had to require_once the first class in the second one, which I wanted to avoid but couldn't

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but are you looking for [call_user_func](http://se.php.net/call_user_func)?

You can call the static method using

```
call_user_func(array('myclass', 'my_method'), $arg1, $arg2, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this myself, but try

```
$some_func = 'my_class::my_method';
```

(e.g. assign the class/method as a string).

This may not work as is, but I do know that something like:

```
$x = 'mysql_real_escape_string';

$sql = "INSERT ... VALUES({$x($_GET['post'])})";
```

does. Ugly, but works.